# How to demo a REST API without a REST client

Tags: rest, demo

I need to build a way to demo a REST API that takes three or four inputs, makes a REST call to an external server, then displays the response. This demo needs to be performed by a rather limited technical audience to business so REST clients are out.

It seemed like a simple HTML page that would do an ajax call would be fine for this, except I ran into the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access` fun messages because my localhost domain does not match the target domain. I don't have access to the target REST web service, so I can't make the necessary changes for the [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) headers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a very small and simple web application that shows the same HTML but does the REST call with its own REST client and shows the results.
Then run that on a local server.

Comment: Yea, this is sort of what I was trying to avoid, but once I put something together, it wasn't so bad. I put it up on an EC2 instance for wider availability.

Comment: Since this is the solution you used, will you accept the answer?

Comment: Sorry, I confused the up vote with the accept. Thanks!! (edit:typo)

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a product where you can host your REST API? (There are number of API hosting products available. )If so you can try [wso2 APImanager](http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/).? It is free and opensource. You do not need to develop any HTML page. You can try available swagger client or REST tool to test your APIs. You can do CORS settings too..

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [ExploREST](https://github.com/Romathonat/ExploREST), a project created with this goal in mind (production demo [here](http://explorest.herokuapp.com/)).

With this tool, you can make **GET**/**POST**/**PUT**/**DEL** requests, but you can also create *special* links in the text documenting your API so that each time someone click on it, it will make the request you defined.

**Example**:

```
## My API is very good, I am documenting it. Try
%{
  "text": "to post",
  "post": {
    "address": "/character",
    "data": {
    "name":"Dark Vador",
    "type": "sith"
    }
  }
}%
```

Will result in a link that make a post when the user clicks on it.
The project is open source so do not hesitate to contribute !